# Vue js, cant pass data

Tags: vue.js

I have simple deposit calc. Here is the code.

app.js:

```
    el: '#calcbox',

data: {

    newCalc: {
        summ: '50000',
        currency: 'USD',
        duration: '',
        percents: '',

    },

    calcResult: '',

},

computed: {

    percents() {

        var id = $("#deposit_id").val();
        var url = "/get_percent/"+ id + '/' + this.newCalc.currency + '/' + this.newCalc.duration;

        this.$http.get(url, function(response){
        return this.newCalc.percents = response;
        });

    },

    calcResult() {

        var deposit_id = $("#deposit_id").val();
        var url = "/api/calc/"+ deposit_id + '/' + this.newCalc.summ + '/' + this.newCalc.currency + '/' + this.newCalc.duration;

        this.$http.get(url, function(response){
        return this.calcResult = response;

        });

    }

},
```

frontend:

```
<span>@{{newCalc.percents}}%:</span>

<span>@{{calcResult}}:</span>
```

So the problem is that result isn't appears in frontend, console.log shows the correct result.

Percentage value is showing well.

Comment: Don't make a `calcResult` *computed* method if you have a `calcResult` data variable. Rename one of them to something different.

Comment: Same with `newCalc.percents`.  Just make them computed properties and don't include them in the data variable.  Furthermore it is best practice to make `data` a function that returns the data object, rather than just an object

Comment: I cant understant why percents are wirking fine, but the result is emty in front. I removed calcResult data variable still nothing.

Comment: @Mistiqe, if you've changed the code, would you please edit your question so we can see what it looks like now?

Answer (score 0):

```
calcResult() {

    var deposit_id = $("#deposit_id").val();
    var url = "/api/calc/"+ deposit_id + '/' + this.newCalc.summ + '/' + this.newCalc.currency + '/' + this.newCalc.duration;

    this.$http.get(url, function(response){
         return this.calcResult = response;
    });

}
```

add .bind(this)

```
 calcResult() {

    var deposit_id = $("#deposit_id").val();
    var url = "/api/calc/"+ deposit_id + '/' + this.newCalc.summ + '/' + this.newCalc.currency + '/' + this.newCalc.duration;

    this.$http.get(url, function(response){
        return this.calcResult = response;

    }.bind(this));

}
```

Or use fat arrow notation since you're using ES6 syntax

```
 calcResult() {

    var deposit_id = $("#deposit_id").val();
    var url = "/api/calc/"+ deposit_id + '/' + this.newCalc.summ + '/' + this.newCalc.currency + '/' + this.newCalc.duration;

    this.$http.get(url, response => {
    return this.calcResult = response;

    });

}
```

the `this` in the `.then` callback is not the same context as the one outside or within your vue method